# Display progress bar dialog on top of modal dialog

Tags: macos, wxwidgets

I am working on a wxWidget-based application. On the Mac, I am trying to open a progress bar dialog on a modal dialog, but it goes behind my modal dialog. While the progress dialog is there, I am not able to perform any operations in application, so functionality-wise it is correct, but I want to bring it to the front, or send my modal dialog behind?

I would really appreciate if someone can point to some code reference as I am new to the Mac API.

Comment: If you've already got a modal window showing, why not just put the progress bar in that window and disable the necessary controls while the task is in progress? Alternatively, put your progress bar on a sheet in front of your modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `wxWindow::Raise()` worked for me.  Also make sure the progress dialog's parent is your modal dialog. With that said, putting the progress bar in the dialog itself would be a lot more slick.